# Are the derived functors of an additive functor additive?

Tags: homological-algebra

Are the derived functors of an additive functor additive? Does  this follows formally from the definition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by definition the derived functor must be a functor of triangulated categories which verifies a certain universal property.

But by definition a functor of triangulated category is additive.